# How to include a value from react state, as a variable, as part of a query parameter in an API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, next.js

I am making an API call, which accepts a query parameter, I would like to input the parameter as a value from state, but I am unable to use ${this.state.mySearch} as a variable in for the query parameter.

I have tried searching on google and seeking help in chat rooms and messed around alot with the code.

```
    state = {
        mySearch: 'apple'
      }
    ...

    ///This API call is defined outside of the main class component(not sure if that is ok)

    Index.getInitialProps = async function() {
      const res = await fetch(
        `https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=${this.state.mySearch}&apiKey=(privateApikey`
      )
      const data = await res.json()

      return {
        headlines: data
      }
    }
```

I expect the API call to be made using the value which is in state, I intend to create a search form which will then allow users to pass in a value to state which will then be used as the variable in the API call.

My error message is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'mySearch' of undefined
Function._callee$
./pages/index.js:52
  49 |   }
  50 | }
  51 | 
> 52 | Index.getInitialProps = async function() {
  53 |   const res = await fetch(
  54 |     `https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=${this.state.mySearch}&apiKey=(myPrivateApiKey)`
  55 |   )
```

Comment: Your function needs to be inside the class if you want to access the state variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that it is defined outside your component-class is the very reason why you are not able to run your API call.

You need to define this in an event-handler inside your component, something like this

```
class Example extends React.Component{
   state = {
      search: "",
      headlines: ""
   }

   handleOnChange = (event) => {
      this.setState({
        search: event.target.value
      })
   }

   handleOnSubmit = async (event) => {
       event.preventDefault()
       const res = await fetch(
       `https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=${this.state.search}&apiKey=(privateApikey`)
       const data = await res.json()

       this.setState({
          headlines: data
       })
   }

   render(){
     return(
     <form onSubmit={this.handleOnSubmit}>
         <input onChange={this.handleOnChange} value={this.state.search}/>
     </form>
    )
   }

}
```